# Edit Home Page which is not part of betterCMS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, bettercms

I have integrated Better CMS in my MVC Website successfully, I have updated the route config so that i can see my own home page

routes.MapRoute("RootPage", "", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", area = "" });

Now I want to change any text on my own home page, is this possible with better CMS, if so is there anyone who can guide me on this?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your home page was stored as a static page (Index.chtml page stored in Home view folder). Better CMS stores its Content in a database, it does not have the capability to edit static pages, all tho its possible to add this. But your Best bet would be to create a new page from within Better CMS [(http://www.bettercms.com/documentation/creating-a-new-page](http://www.bettercms.com/documentation/creating-a-new-page)), If you are concerned about the layout of the page this can be changed by creating [Page templates](https://github.com/devbridge/BetterCMS/wiki/Server-Side-Templates-for-Developers), [Client Side Templates](https://github.com/devbridge/BetterCMS/wiki/Client-Side-Templates) and theming properly. You can create the templates against most bootstrap themes.

Here are some good links to information from the source.

https://www.devbridge.com/articles/better-cms-for-developers/
https://github.com/devbridge/BetterCMS/wiki

I hope this helps.
You can inbox me if you need any information.

Answer (score 0):

One option that comes to my mind would be to create a New Page in BetterCMS with all the text/content you want to display in your MVC Homepage. And then, make an Ajax call from your MVC Homepage to retrieve BetterCMS page, scrape sections you require from it and attach it to your Homepage.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a server side template out of your home page by setting the index.cshtml view's layout to BetterCMS's base layout, and pull the "options" from a newly created BCMS created page. You'll set the name and path of the template in the Page's properties. See Better CMS's github wiki "Serverside Templates" documentation.